# How to use @Path to set a rest url (get a link to view a file)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc

I upload a text file to the server and save its contents to the database (the database stores the contents of my downloaded text file). How to make a rest-url to my record (each record has its own url).For example, I sent a file, the contents of the file were saved in the database and I received a link to view this file. I read somewhere that it can be done with @Path, but I can't figure out how to do it

```
/*Uploading files and his division for line in line. Save in database*/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                String completeData = new String(bytes);

                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File( "-uploaded")));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                /*Data for doc_add_date*/
                Calendar calendar_add_date = Calendar.getInstance();
                Timestamp doc_add_date = new Timestamp(calendar_add_date.getTime().getTime());

                /*Data for doc_mod_date*/
                Calendar calendar_mod_date = Calendar.getInstance();
                Timestamp doc_mod_date = new Timestamp(calendar_mod_date.getTime().getTime());

                /*generation UUID*/
                UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                String uuidStr = uuid.toString();
                /*Result*/
                dao.add_b_utmdocs(completeData, doc_add_date, doc_mod_date, uuidStr);

                return "redirect:/home";
            } 
    }
```

After downloading the file and saving its contents to the DB, I expect to get a link to view this content (I use JDBC connection and Spring Boot)

Comment: `/upload/{id}`, where id is the primary key value of the row where you saved the file?

Comment: Hey. Id is automatically generated. Now, I just go to the postman at the POST http://localhost:8080/upload and send a text file, and the content is added to the database(in the database stored ID, completeData, doc_add_date, doc_mod_date, uuidStr). Sorry, I just started learning Java and Spring boot. I will be glad of any help

Comment: My database:

id (integer) - primary key is stored;
body (text) - stores the contents of my file;
doc_add_date (timestamp) - date and time when the file was uploaded;
doc_mod_date (timestamp) - date and time when the file was uploaded; 
doc_reply_id (character varies 1000) - UUID

Comment: So your question actually is: "how to get the value of an autogenerated ID using JDBC?", right? If that is so, copy and paste that question into google, then click on the first returned link.

Comment: And if the ID is your UUID, then you don't need to do anything: you already have it, since you're the one who generated it.

Comment: No. Once I've uploaded the file, I want to get a link to it (each entry has its own link). For example:
There are three records in the database and each record has its own URL to view this record.
For example, the first entry here is a link opt/file/1
The second entry is the link to opt/file/2
and so on

Comment: The UUID I have done so far for another job

Comment: OK. That's what you want. But what is your *question*? What prevents you from doing it?

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that. In the Internet examples not found, maybe I'm bad looking (was looking for two days). But somewhere I read what you can do with @Path to set the rest-url. I don't know. I will be glad of any help, even a link to the article

Comment: Path is a JAX-RS annotation. You're using a different web framework: Spring MVC. I still don't understand what is the concrete problem you're facing: listing all the uploaded files? Deciding how the URL to a file should look like? Getting the ID of the uploaded file? Declaring a method allowing to read a file? What?

Comment: How do I make a url to each file. So I can go to this url and see my file. So that each entry has its own url

Comment: You can not view the file directly. You have to write the code to download (similar way you written for upload)the file and view that downloaded file

Comment: `/upload/{id}`, where id is the primary key value of the row where you saved the file? That was my first comment. So if the ID of the row holding the file you want to see is 1234, the URL would be /upload/1234. That is your URL. Is your actual question "how to declare a Spring MVC method that is mapped to that URL?"? If so, it would be `@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. The method would has a `@PathVariable("id")` annotated argument to let you get the ID, and would need to read your file from the database and send it as a response.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the Spring MVC documentation, because this is fundamental stuff that you need to learn. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html

Comment: Thanks. Thanks for the link. I'm sorry I'm not clear on my question. I'll try to do it now

Comment: I read about @PathVariable. Not impossible to do. Wrote here is such code:
    @RequestMapping(value = "opt/out/{bud_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getId(@PathVariable("doc_reply_id") int bud_id){
        return bud_id;
    }
What is wrong?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using @RequestMapping(value = "/upload/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)